# Matlab's TreeBagger and k-fold cross validation

Tags: matlab, random-forest, cross-validation, decision-tree, k-fold

I am trying to get the 5-fold cross validation error of a model created with TreeBagger using the function crossval but I keep getting an error

> Error using crossval>evalFun
> The function 'regrTree' generated the following error:
> Too many input arguments.

My code is below. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

```
%Random Forest
%%XX is training data matrix, Y is training labels vector
XX=X_Tbl(:,2:end);
Forest_Mdl = TreeBagger(1000,XX,Y,'Method','regression');

err_std = crossval('mse',XX,Y,'Predfun',@regrTree, 'kFold',5);


function yfit_std = regrTree(Forest_Mdl,XX) 
yfit_std = predict(Forest_Mdl,XX);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reading the documentation helps a lot!:](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html#mw_c4fce135-a041-4f4d-b449-703a77483294)

The function has to be defined as:

(note that it takes 3 arguments, not 2)

> ```
> function yfit = myfunction(Xtrain,ytrain,Xtest)
> % Calculate predicted response
> ...
> end
> ```
>
> Xtrain — Subset of the observations in X used as training predictor
> data. The function uses Xtrain and ytrain to construct a
> classification or regression model.
>
> ytrain — Subset of the responses in y used as training response data.
> The rows of ytrain correspond to the same observations in the rows of
> Xtrain. The function uses Xtrain and ytrain to construct a
> classification or regression model.
>
> Xtest — Subset of the observations in X used as test predictor data.
> The function uses Xtest and the model trained on Xtrain and ytrain to
> compute the predicted values yfit.
>
> yfit — Set of predicted values for observations in Xtest. The yfit
> values form a column vector with the same number of rows as Xtest.